# What is the best and most efficient method of fetching the maximum value from an Int column?

Tags: swift2, realm

What is the best and most efficient method of fetching the maximum value from an Int column?

Idea A

```
let maxId = realm.objects(Books).sorted("id").last
```

Idea B

```
let maxId = realm.objects(Books).sorted("id", ascending: false).first
```

Or another idea?

(Yes my code snippets will only return the object with the highest ID, not the actual value)

Comment: Just looked into source code of realm and there is presented  a method `max<U: MinMaxType>(property: String) ` .  The end result it should look  like below
`Realm().objects(Books).max("id")` OR
`realm.objects(Books).max("id")`
Here is the link to the source
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift-swift2.0/Results.swift
Please Correct me If I'm wrong :)

Comment: :(  
All I'm getting is "generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred".  The docs sure point to what you suggest being possible.  I've tried all manner of combinations for using 'max' that I can think of but no success.

Comment: Sorry if my suggestion sounds naive, but
Have you tried to make it working this way?
`realm.objects(Books).max("id") as Int?`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it should work in the following way

```
 if let maxValue =  realm.objects(Books).max("id") as Int?{

 // Do some stuff 
 }
```

Or just

```
let maxValue =  realm.objects(Books).max("id") as Int?
```

To make my answer complete I decided to add the code to fetch the min value:
`realm.objects(Books).min("id") as Int?`

Comment: Whoever Down-voted my answer should leave the comment why!

Answer (score 23):

Following on from @ProblemSlover's answer.   I created a small app that throws 10000 records into a realm class - calling a function to fetch the max value and using that to set the ID column.  I wanted to see some metrics (I ran the test 3 times to get an average).  As you can see the MAX function is 2.3 times quicker than sorted/last and nearly 8 times quicker than ascending/first.  Sometimes it's just good to know.  :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this graph. Can someone explain the huge difference between ascending/first and sorted/last?

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4 and Xcode 9.3**

I tried ProblemSlover's answer - but it doesn't work anymore...

But give this a try:

```
let maxValue =  realm.objects(Books).max(ofProperty: "id") as Int?
```